# Why do I get a 403 error when calling a WCF Webservice?

Tags: wcf, soap

I'm really posting this question so that others searching for the answer can find it.

Scenario:
WCF Service: Has worked fine at some point but currently is returning 403 errors.  The web.config looks fine as far as I can tell.  This machine has set the web.config to disable transport and message security and is using BasicHTTPBinding.

When I call it with my client generated from the Service Reference in Visual Studio, I get a 403 error.   The error indicates there is some problem with the authentication, but as far as I can tell there is no such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used Fiddler to get the actual error code - in this case, a 403.1.  This indicated that the executable for the service couldn't be run.

The actual problem ended up being that the ASP.NET version was set to 1.1, not 2.0+.  So setting that to 2.0 resolved the 403 permission error.

Answer (score 0):

Http 403 error is "Forbidden". There is something that is blocking access.

In cases where it worked at one point and then stopped, it is often a windows update that has tightend up the security.

- Where is your WCF service installed?
- What are the ACL's on these files?
- What is the security context of your service? (Which account will be used to access the files)
- Does that user have access to the files?

Comment: See the below solution.  Any of the above could have been the problem, but a 403 can also come from the ASP.NET version being wrong.